# How can I fit the A595 of my unknown samples to the data?

Tags: methods

While I was conducting the Bradford Assay experiment to determine the concentration of my unknowns, I ended up by having an A595 for my unknown samples that is higher than the A595 of the standards. How can I resolve this issue?
wishes.. Micheal.

Comment: Just find out slop of your standard curve and then calculate unknown concentration from that. [this](http://www.chm.davidson.edu/vce/spectrophotometry/unknownsolution.html) might be helpful to you.

Comment: When you run a bradford assay the bound form of the dye shifts the absorption max to 595nm. This is what your spectrometer should be set to when you're running the assay. You make a standard graph because you can calculate an extinction coefficient ε from the slope of the graph. Beer's law says that A = εcl where your path length is determined by the cuvette you used, and c is your concentration. So you take your absorption that you obtained and solve for c! Canadianer makes an excellent point below, however, so make sure your methods make sense!

Answer (score 1):

You could, depending on what you are doing, extrapolate your standard curve to include the absorbance of your samples. This, however, is not recommended since absorbance is linear only within a certain range. It's best to dilute your samples so that they fall within the range of the standard curve while also ensuring that your standard curve is, in fact, linear.